# cut a sprite sheet on cocos2d for animation

Tags: iphone, sdk, cocos2d-iphone

I want to cut a sprite in 6 equivalent parts just with one image, a .png file which I found on the web, no with texturepacker, (the image below by example)

I can take other way, but I want to know if I can do that. any one haves idea?

[image]

Comment: I think it's unclear what you are asking. Are you asking how to make 6 separate .pngs to save to disk out of that one? Are you asking how to use the png as is, but as an animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll revise my answer if this isn't what you were asking about, but I think you are asking how to 'manually run an animation' using a spritesheet without a plist.
Here's one way. It would be better if you encapsulated this into it's own class, but this can push you in the right direction I think:

ManualAnimationTest.h

```
@interface ManualAnimationTest : CCLayer
{
    CCSprite *animatedSprite;
    int x,y;
    float animatedSpriteWidth, animatedSpriteHeight;
    int animatedSpriteColumns, animatedSpriteRows;
}
@end
```

ManualAnimationTest.m

```
#import "ManualAnimationTest.h"

@implementation ManualAnimationTest
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]))
    {
        CGSize s = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
        x = 0;
        y = 0;

        animatedSpriteColumns = 3;
        animatedSpriteRows = 2;
        animatedSpriteWidth = 95.0f;
        animatedSpriteHeight = 125.0f;

        animatedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"animal_animation.png" rect:CGRectMake(x * animatedSpriteWidth,y * animatedSpriteHeight,animatedSpriteWidth,animatedSpriteHeight)];

        [self addChild:animatedSprite];
        [animatedSprite setPosition:ccp(s.width / 2.0f, s.height / 2.0f)];
        [self schedule:@selector(animateAnimatedSprite) interval:0.5f];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) animateAnimatedSprite
{
    [animatedSprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(x * animatedSpriteWidth, y * animatedSpriteHeight, animatedSpriteWidth, animatedSpriteHeight)];
    x +=1;
    if(x > (animatedSpriteColumns - 1))
    {
        x = 0;
        y +=1;
    }

    if(y > (animatedSpriteRows - 1))
    {
        y = 0;
    }
}


@end
```